# Opera 40 not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: browser

[image: can't reach any site except Google]

I've installed Opera 40 x64 and it isn't working. I can't reach any site except Google. But Firefox is working well. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If another browser works ... check the proxy server settings in opera (as told in the message). If that is set and set wrongly sites error out.

Comment: I checked, there's no no proxy server